# Storing query result in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hy! Is there any option to storing query results in a table clob field? For example after opening a command window and running queries after I want to store any kind of script output (oracle error codes too if any script run would crash) to database table. Like a spool command but not in a file.

```
CREATE TABLE queries 
 (
  query_result CLOB
 );
```

After opening a command window

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR
2    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
3    FROM DUAL;
NOW
-------------------
09-14-2021 20:18:16
```

And I want to store "09-14-2021 20:18:16" to `queries.query_result` field.

Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to multiply your data for as much times as there was a "views" of the data. It's quite pointless. I.e. if someone will run `select * from big table` and fetch only 100 rows to the client, you will save all the data in the table as a clob.

Comment: The point was feasibility. Otherwise,I will not use it for data duplication
I want to save the results from the command line window, the question is, how.

Comment: So should your database know the type of the client application that ran the command? If the same was executed by, for example, SQL Developer that allows SQL*plus-like features via F5? And what if this command produce gigabytes of data as output? Feasibility is not a purpose, according to the question guide question should have [practical application](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Just talk about simple commands with negligible output please.

Comment: _"Just talk about simple commands with negligible output please"_  So at what point does the output become NOT negligible?  @astentx has a valid point.  Just like another thread I just commented on, this smells like an [XY Problem.](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: It really looks like you *think* you should do this, but the overall task is different. 1) Why do you care what is my client app? It's my business what to use. Anyway it can easily be set to what I want or I can connect via different tool but do the same things. You shouldn't care about the tool, but only about my actions. 2) You cannot see what I see (because not all operations can be replayed with the same result). To guarantee this you need some proxy code to provide MITM. 3) Code can use bind variables, you will not get their values to replay my statement. So what is the **real** task?

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is called [auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000). I'd suggest you not to reinvent the wheel, but use what Oracle already provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html) to generate an XML representation for the results of any query.

For example, run the query in the below statement. Don't forget to remove the trailing semicolon.

```
insert into queries
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml
    (q'[
        SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW" FROM DUAL
    ]')
from dual;
```

The results will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <NOW>09-14-2021 23:26:25</NOW>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

You could automate this with a PL/SQL script, but I'm not sure how you would get it to automatically run as part of a tool like SQL Developer.